# How to change the order of CD-ROM drives in Windows?

Tags: windows, dvd, virtual-drive, cd-drive

Is there a way to change the order/position of CD-ROM drives in Windows? I have used Daemon tools to mount a virtual disc and I want to change its position to first i.e. 0.

[image: Here's an image of Disk Management.]

The first one is the physical CD-ROM drive, second is the mounted one. I want to change mounted drive to position 0. I tried disabling the physical drive through device manager, but it requires a restart and upon restarting, it gets enabled again.

Comment: I was about to comment about swapping SATA cables and then saw that the second one was a virtual drive.  Umm.  If plug and play SATA is enabled on your motherboard, you could boot without the physical drive plugged in, mount the virtual drive, then plug in the physical drive.  I'm not certain what this will accomplish, however.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the Virtual or non virtual CD/DVD Drive it should you give you the following option, click on it and change the letter.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this changes the drive letter only. Drive position will remain the same. i.e. CD-ROM 0 shall remain CD-ROM 0. As visible in the image from question, the mounted drive is G: while the physical is I: Mounted should have been CD-ROM 0.